# Replace TRANSPARENT part of image set in imageview with another image?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

How to change TRANSPARENT part of image set in imageview with another image?

Below is the main image, there is TRANSPARENT portion(here looks white), i want to set another image withing that portion of image.

any idea how to do it?

Question:

1. How to find TRANSPARENT portion starting point LEFT(x,y), RIGHT (x,y), BOTTOM LEFT (x,y), BOTTOM RIGHT(x,y) ? for image replacement.
2. How to process bitmap in runtime to add another image to make changes in imageview?

I've tried [this to find transparent part of image](http://brownandroidattack.blogspot.in/2010/03/image-transparency-aka-absurd.html).

[image: actual skin image]

Comment: This has to be done totally programatically or does the user interact ?

Comment: programatically, based on other preference/choices different images should be set inside transparent part automatically.

Comment: What do you need help with? Are you wondering about how to get alpha of a pixel or something? An average programmer should easily have done this.

Comment: complete pixels location of start & end of transparent part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this example in this crop image with transparent part it will use full for  you.
https://github.com/ketanpatel25/Image-Cropping-In-Transparent-Area

Answer (score 1):

You have a bitmap (B1) and there is only one rectangle transparent zone somewhere. And you want to place another bitmap (B2) inside it.

- use monte-carlo method to find any transparent pixel on B1. You know 
  it's coordinates now.
- go [left/right/top/bottom] from transparent pixel and find
  first solid pixel. Now you know transparent rectangle coorditates.

There are several ways to put something inside transparent area. You can:

- place second imageview (with B2) under the first one (with B1). Set B2 padding inside imageview accordingly transparent zone coordinates.
- create new image from B1 and B2 and set it to imageview.
- do it some other way...